# localhost page not showing the proper output of php code

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RpJ2.png)
i have switched on my Apache through xampp. opened the folder in htdocs. then wrote the "hello". but after refreshing the page just goes blank.

i was expecting the string to be on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Apache server is running 100%, and then put it in the URL: http://localhost/370_PRAC. The index.php file will execute from this folder.

It should be displayed "hello"

Comment: ikr. but its not working.  xmapp is showing apache and sql is running and url is also correct. Just cant figure out whats the problem